# Quickbooks online API - multiple SaaS tennant setup

Tags: php, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When you get an incoming call in to the OAuth auth handler page, how can it determine which tenant it is for? There is the line with the call to

```
if ($IntuitAnywhere->handle($the_username, $the_tenant))
```

See [Oauth.php L23](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/f0947cbe274836e27c05514d0ea6f1bc6126300d/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/oauth.php#L23)

How do I get a value for `$the_tenant`? Is there something in the incoming data to determine which one it is for?

Answer (score 0):

The `$the_tenant` variable is *yours to use as you see fit*. You don't *get* the value -- you *set* the value.

So, if someone is connecting to QuickBooks, presumably you know who they are already, right? They have logged in to your website/app and are now trying to connect your website/app to QuickBooks. Presumably then, you already know what `tenant` within *your* application they belong to... and that `tenant` or user has an identifier of some sort within your own website/app.

So you need to *set* `$the_tenant` to YOUR tenant/user identifier value.

Comment: I know the value of $the_tenant when calling out, but  the OAuth handler page is getting an incoming call from QBOE. I might have multiple tenants trying to connect around the same timeframe, but when I get a callback from QBOE, how do I know which tenant the incoming call is for?

Comment: That's not how OAuth works ^^^. OAuth bounces the end user from your website, to Intuit's, and then *back to your website*. Which means the user is going to be logged in to your website both before they leave your site, AND after they get redirected back to your site. There's no separate out-of-band callback from QBOE happening, it's all just the users' browser getting redirected back and forth. So if you're keeping track of who the person is with a cookie, then you'll always have that cookie available to you, both before and after OAuth.